# Get Twitter user id via HTTP request encoded in JSON format

Tags: android, json, twitter

I'm working on a backend platform for a client in which he can add users and their twitter username. The frontend is an android/ios application in which the app's users can open a twitter app intent.

For android it seems to be that the code is the following:

```
int userId;
try {
        getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id="+userId));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/"+userId));
    }
    this.startActivity(intent);
```

So It seems that I NEED to use the user id instead of the username.

So I was wondering if there is any way to make a POST/GET request to twitter in order to get a username's user_id, if possible enconded in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
Uri.parse("twitter://user?screen_name="+username)
```